# 400 when accessing shared file using graph api with shared url

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I called the endpoint `/shares/{shareId}` using msgraph-sdk-php, but got response 400 as:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#shares/$entity",
  "id":"s!here-is-the-share-id",
  "name@odata.type":"#String",
  "name":{ 
    "error": { 
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": "A primitive value was specified; however, a value of the non-primitive type '' was expected.", 
      "innerError": { 
        "request-id": "3ea56b1c-acd6-4fdf-a856-c46b35e01cb7", 
        "date": "2017-05-25T05:26:23"
      } 
    } 
  } 

(Yes, I even got 4 left brackets but only 3 right brackets.)
```

while I can get correct response via `api.onedrive.com` api with the same `shareId`.
I really can't find any tips from documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know about this @SevenOutman! This was a configuration issue that has now been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and efforts.